# Unable to reach a specific xpath location in for-each loop

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

In for-each loop i am unable to reach in a xpath saying the error:

**Error:**

```
XPTY0020: Cannot select a node here: the context item is an atomic value
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
                        <CommlCoverage>
                        <Form>
                            <FormNumber id="XP149NEW">XP149</FormNumber>
                            <FormName>XP218 NON-FOLLOWED ENDORSEMENT</FormName>

                                <FormText QuestionCd="XP149_cov_desc" arrayId="101">XP149 cov desc 1</FormText>
                                <FormText QuestionCd="XP149_underly_limit" arrayId="101">1000001</FormText>

                                <FormText QuestionCd="XP149_cov_desc" arrayId="102">XP149 cov desc 2</FormText>
                                <FormText QuestionCd="XP149_underly_limit" arrayId="102">2000001</FormText>
                                

                                <FormText QuestionCd="XP149_cov_desc" arrayId="103">XP149 cov desc 3</FormText>
                                <FormText QuestionCd="XP149_underly_limit" arrayId="103">3000001</FormText>

                                <FormText QuestionCd="XP149_array">101,102,103</FormText>
                        </Form>
                        </CommlCoverage>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

    <xsl:template match="CommlCoverage">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Transformation</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize((//Form[FormNumber='XP149']/FormText[@QuestionCd='XP149_array']), ',')">
                    
                    <!-- Assigning token value in id variable -->
                    <xsl:variable name="id" select="string(.)"/>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td border="1pt solid" display-align="center">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            <!-- When i try to use $id in xpath then error is coming as above --> 
                            <!--<xsl:value-of select="//Form[FormText[@QuestionCd='XP149_cov_desc' and @arrayId=$id]]/FormText"/>-->
                        </td>
                        <td border="1pt solid" display-align="center">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            <!-- When i try to use $id in xpath then error is coming as above --> 
                            <!--<xsl:value-of select="//FormText[@QuestionCd='XP149_underly_limit' and @arrayId=$id]"/>-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: this is dedicated link to demonstrate: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxWZS7y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `for-each` processing the result of a `tokenize` call the context item is a string, if you need to access nodes from the document declare a variable, e.g. `<xsl:variable name="main-doc" select="/"/>` before the `xsl:for-each`, then, for any node selection start with `$main-doc` e.g. `$main-doc//Form`.

Comment: Wow thanks its works https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxWZS7y/1

Answer (score 1):

OR, it can be done in other way by using `for-each-group`:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Form/FormText" group-by="@arrayId">
    <tr>
        <td border="1pt solid" display-align="center">
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[@QuestionCd='XP149_cov_desc']"/>
        </td>
        <td border="1pt solid" display-align="center">
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[@QuestionCd='XP149_underly_limit']"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
    <title>Transformation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <tr>
      <td border="1pt solid" display-align="center">XP149 cov desc 1</td>
      <td border="1pt solid" display-align="center">1000001</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td border="1pt solid" display-align="center">XP149 cov desc 2</td>
      <td border="1pt solid" display-align="center">2000001</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td border="1pt solid" display-align="center">XP149 cov desc 3</td>
      <td border="1pt solid" display-align="center">3000001</td>
    </tr>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually my real scenarioes is litle complex and already at top level grouping done. so grouping inside is leanthy that's why i prefer above one concept. Thanks again